# Uploadify control in a div INSIDE a table cell

Tags: html, jquery-plugins

I've got the following control working called Uploadify. So I've placed the control inside a table. Here's a rough example:

```
<tr>
<td>
     <div id="holdcontrol"> 
     <input id="file_upload" name="file_upload" type="file" />
     </div>
    </td>
<td> OTHER STUFF </td>
</tr>
<tr>
```

The control is placed in a div called "holdcontrol". It is not possible to use hide or attr to disable the uploadify control because of its flash content. The simple solution is to simply set the height of the div to zero.

So I used $(#holdcontrol).css("height", 0); - so this "disables" the control which really 'hides' the button.

The problem is that it only partially closes down on the Uploadify control - Half of it - Which means that I can see "half of the control button". When I want to use the control again, I issue the command:

$(#holdcontrol).css("height", null); - that rebounds and it works fine. It's the setting of the div height inside the table cell to "hide" or to "disable" the Uploadify control that is bugging me.

Any thoughts or tips to truly setting that div height value to 0?

thanks and Happy Holidays!

Answer (score 0):

After uploadify is loaded it changes your HTML code using JavaScript. In one of my Projects it adds an object outside of **#holdcontrol** so hiding **#holdcontrol** won't do anything.

```
<div id="holdcontrol"> 
    <input id="file_upload" name="file_upload" type="file" />
</div>
<object 
    width="226" height="24" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
    data="http://www.example.com/ext/flash/uploadify.swf" 
    id="flashfileUploader"        
>
    <!-- even more code-->
</object>
```

As you can see the object gets the id **#flashfileUploader** - so if you just try to change **#flashfileUploader** instead of **#holdcontrol** you should be fine.

You can find this kind of undocumented stuff using FireBug (https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/1843/).

so long,
Tim